# Few doubts about saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I have some sort of confusions  towards   saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure.. So let me  give you those.

---

1. What is **exactly** saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure and  how do they form?
2. What is the **difference** between  saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure.?
3. Is it possible to measure the **variation** of  saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure  **with temperature** , separately , if so how can I do it ?
4. What is the **connection** between  saturated vapour pressure and unsaturated vapour pressure  with **Charle's law.**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you take liquid water for example and start heating it at atmospheric pressure, the temperature increases. It corresponds to following a horizontal line along $p=p_{atmospheric}$ on the above graph. Under liquid state, the volume is small hence it corresponds to the left region on the graph.

If you keep heating, the liquid will start turning into vapor when temperature 100°C is reached. At this point, the temperature and the pressure will remain constant while the liquid will keep turning into vapor as you heat. In this configuration the vapor is said to be saturated because there is still liquid water(correspond to zone between A and B on the graph).

The conclusion is that at 100°C, the saturated pressure is p=1atm.

If now you close the recipient where you have your water(like in a pressure cooker), the pressure will start increasing as more and more vapor is formed. It would correspond to following a vertical line from on the graph. 
In that case as you keep heating, the water will start boiling again at a higher temperature.

The conclusion this time will be that at 120°C the saturated pressure is a bit more than $p=1atm$.

The saturated pressure is described by the dotted red curve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hey could you describe little bit more about the stuffs in the graph you given. Because I didn't understand the description  what you wrote  for that graph .